# Why do Kotlin Sets have indices?

Tags: kotlin, set

I'm curious as to why Kotlin `Set`s have indices. You can access elements by using `mySet.elementAt(index)`. No other language I know has this feature. Is the feature any useful if sets aren't supposed to be ordered and yet they have indices? Also, doesn't this feature make `Set`s in Kotlin slower than other `Set`s in other languages?

Comment: I don't know Kotlin so I can't give you a definitive answer, but it's not that strange for a nominally unordered data structure to have some sort of order. For example, Python `dict`s recently started guaranteeing insertion order, though there's still no integer indexing. Looking it up, Kotlin `Set`s are the immutable version. That's even easier to implement indices for, no need to worry about inserting new elements in the middle of the order.

Comment: @BatWannaBe yeah but `MutableSet`s also have this index element access.

Comment: If I'm looking at the right place, the comments in `Sets.kt` on `MutableSet`s say "Elements of the set are iterated in the order they were specified." If insertion order is maintained, all you have to do to find the `i`-th element is start at the 0th element and iterate `i` times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Set` has the `elementAt` method, not because it is based on indices (so it is not "slower than other languages" just because it has this method), but because it implements [`Iterable<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterable/). `elementAt` is an extension function on `Iterable<T>`:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.elementAt(index: Int): T
```

What a `Set` is based on depends on which concrete implementation of `Set` you use (`Set` is just an interface). `HashSet` is based on a hash table, for example.

So `Set` gets this `elementAt` method "for free" just because it implements `Iterable<T>`. The only way for it to *not* have `elementAt` is to not implement `Iterable<T>`, but that would mean you can't iterate over a `Set`. That's not very useful, is it? Also, as I'll talk about later, `elementAt` does have its uses.

Since `elementAt` is an extension function on `Iterable<T>`, all it can do really, is to ask to the iterator to give it n elements, and return the last element. This is how it is [implemented](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/34e57a45f2d4283be572137b4b497414b8833ee7/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L84).

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.elementAt(index: Int): T {
    if (this is List)
        return get(index)
    return elementAtOrElse(index) { throw IndexOutOfBoundsException("Collection doesn't contain element at index $index.") }
}

...

public fun <T> Iterable<T>.elementAtOrElse(index: Int, defaultValue: (Int) -> T): T {
    if (this is List)
        return this.getOrElse(index, defaultValue)
    if (index < 0)
        return defaultValue(index)
    val iterator = iterator()
    var count = 0
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        val element = iterator.next()
        if (index == count++)
            return element
    }
    return defaultValue(index)
}
```

If your `Set` does not have a particular order (e.g. `HashSet`), then its iterator will return elements in no particular order either, so using `elementAt(x)` is not very meaningful. On the other hand, if you are using an ordered set, like a `LinkedHashSet` (this is what `setOf` and `mutableSetOf` creates), then using `elementAt` does make sense.

Also note that `elementAt` does have O(n) time, but that doesn't mean that accessing the set using the set's methods (e.g. `contains`) also has O(n) time. That also depends on which concrete implementation of `Set` you use. Both `LinkedHashSet.contains` and `HashSet.contains` are O(1) time.

Comment: So the [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) implemented by Kotlin's stdlib is [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) that includes the [axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice)?  :-)

Comment: Thank you for this really detailed explanaition referencing the actual Kotlin library code. I get it now :)